# How Can I access File from Windows CE mobile to my desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I want to access .sdf file from windows ce mobile to my desktop application in C#.How can i access .sdf file from windows CE mobile.How can i find path of that sdf which is stored in windows ce mobile.

Comment: From which end?  You want a PC app to move the file, or the device application?

Comment: i want Pc app.I want static path how can i Find static path of windows mobile.i want to access .sdf file which is store in windows program file and i want that sdf file in my desktop app. how i connect that sdf file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use RAPI to access your sdf file. but it's very trick to access from pc to mobile device. it's better to move your sdf file from mobile to pc and use that file.

Answer (score 2):

There is microsoft article about that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307256. 
It uses RemotePAI to access your device.

Here is some similar example : http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2007/06/copying-files-from-device-to-desktop.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A connected device does not have a local path.  The "My Device" you see in Explorer is just a trick of a shell extension.  To get device files, you have to use RAPI.  [There's a .NET wrapper for it here](http://rapi.codeplex.com/).